# Windows 8.1 100% disk usage

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance, ssd, resource-usage

Sorry to make another one of these posts, but I've dug through at least a dozen other threads and no other solution has worked for me.  My problem also seems to be slightly different.

[image: Task Manager]

As you can see, I'm using 100% of disk usage, which is causing my computer to be extremely slow, but it doesn't appear that any process is actually using the disk to an significant degree.

I have had this problem on and off for about a year now with a desktop gaming PC I've had for about two years.  Storage is on a 2tb hard disk, with a 128gb ssd being used for SSD Caching.  I've never figured out what makes the problem start or go away, the problem appears to happen when I boot the computer up every once in a while, I typically try and fail to fix it, and it eventually goes away, sometimes after a restart, sometimes not.

Some things I've tried:

1) Changing the paging file size as per this thread: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/windows-8-keeps-slows-down-to-100-disk-usage-and/cd787f8d-e7b4-4872-aecb-6f0cd15ad942

2) disabling superfetch and windows search

3) updating drivers (I think I've updated just about everything...)

3) restarting.  Like a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well simplest way; start killing processes until you find the culprit then address why that process is causing your hdd to thrash.

Comment: If killing processes was the solution, wouldn't task manager show the process that was taking up so much disk use?  There's also dozens of processes, many of which are system processes I cannot kill without having to restart the computer.

Comment: It is... 7MB/Sec is pretty significant usage on top of the other 5MB/sec usage.

Comment: yeah i think you can go with steam starting at login is the problem here

Comment: It doesn't start at login, I started it.  Also, that 99% usage stays continuously, not just on startup.  Running steam and chrome at the same time (with no games) should not constitute 99% disk usage continuously and cause my computer to be extremely difficult to use, particularly when at least some of these files are being accessed of a separate SSD.  This is something that comes up periodically, I know for a fact that I can run that and far more without practically crashing my computer.  Literally typing into windows search is enough to spike it back to 100% usage.

Comment: follow this http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60 and give me the file or analyze it yourself: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis

Answer (score 2):

After hours of continuing to dig through forums, I finally found the culprit.  For some reason, my SSD caching was causing the problem.  I have no idea why this would be, and why the problem would occur only sporadically, but disabling SSD caching appears to have had an immediate and dramatic effect.

Answer (score -2):

This can cause high CPU use in windwos 8.1 and may effect your problem?

In Windows 8.1, when the user account name contains the word "user",   intermittently you will find the process taskhost.exe keeps consuming high CPU percentage.
This is a problem in the component DFPCommon.dl in Windows 8.1.
To resolve the issue, do not create a user account contains the string "user" on the computer.
Applies to
Windows 8.1, Windows 8.1 Enterprise, Windows 8.1 Pro, Windows 8.1 with Bing 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3053711

Comment: Please properly cite and quote your source. I will reverse my downvote when that happens.